# Jquery Wordpress not working without admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with a site I am making.
JQuery is not loading without being logged in as admin
if i am a visitor it gives this error
[error without admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNlJ9.png)

If I am connected instead I get this back
[admin account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/robKr.jpg)

These are the plugins I'm using
[plugins list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHdcr.png)

Comment: you are deferring your jquery - but none of your other scripts - So jquery isn't loaded, when scripts that depends on jquery is loaded.

Comment: So the problem is in your siteground optimizer

Answer (score 0):

Please try deactivating the site ground plugins and maintenance plugins then check again. These errors are coming from Elementor as it can't find the jquery dependency in the header. This happens when optimization plugins move jquery to the bottom of the page which should not be done generally as a lot of plugins are dependent on that and we should load it in the header itself.

Comment: Or exclude jQuery from js defer in SiteGround optimizer

Comment: Agree with @MosheGross